# Auto Logout function is not 100% working for Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, community, visualforce-component

I have written an auto logout function for a community portal. This is inside a visualforce component and this has been exposed to a visualforce page. The problem  here is this auto logout function perfectly working when we are in the relavant browser tab. But this is not working when we are in another tab. Can someone help me to solve this out?

```
    function idleLogout() {
        
        window.onload = resetTimer;
        window.onmousemove = resetTimer;
        window.onmousedown = resetTimer;  
        window.ontouchstart = resetTimer; 
        window.onclick = resetTimer;     
        window.onkeydown = resetTimer;   
        window.onkeyup = resetTimer;   
        window.addEventListener('onload', resetTimer, true);    
    }
```

Comment: to clarify, this code works when the tab is in focus, but not when it is a background tab in the browser?

Comment: @MarkPond You are correct. Also suppose the browser tab is open and screen is on sleep mode. In that case also this is not working